# How to compare user input in array?

Tags: java

Hi guys sorry I'm a newbie to Java, this is one of the exercise in my class.
I supposed to ask user input 5 numbers, then compare them if they are the same number that entered before. 
These are my code so far, but I can't get it work.
Thanks.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Source {
    private static int num = 0;
    private static int[] enterednum = new int[5];

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        for(int count = 0; count < enterednum.length; count++) {
            System.out.println("Enter a number.");
            num = input.nextInt();

            compare(enterednum);
        }

        System.out.println("These are the number you have entered: ");
        System.out.println(enterednum);
    }

    public static void compare(int[] enterednum) {
        for(int count = 0; count < 6; count++)
            if(num == enterednum[count])
                System.out.println("The number has been entered before.");
    }
}
```

Comment: What specifically is the problem? I mean, what do you mean when you said _I can't get it work_

Comment: Why are you running count for 6 times?Use the same `.length` property?

Comment: It has errors when try to run it. @kaonashi

Comment: Yeah didn't realize that... Thanks ! @SatejS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want something like this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Source 
{
    private static int enterednum[]=new int[5];
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        int num=0; // make this local variable since this need not be class property
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);


        for(int count=0;count<enterednum.length;count++)
        {
            System.out.println("Enter a number.");
            num = input.nextInt();
            compare(num, count);
            enterednum[count] = num; // store the input


        }

        System.out.println("These are the number you have entered: ");
        // print numbers in array instead the array
        for(int count=0;count<enterednum.length;count++)
        {
            System.out.println(enterednum[count]);
        }
    }
    // change the method signature to let it get the number of input
    public static void compare(int num, int inputcount)
    {
        for(int count=0;count<inputcount;count++)
        {
            if(num==enterednum[count])
                System.out.println("The number has been entered before.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks ! I will try it !

Answer (score 0):

You can do this way if you need.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.*;

public class Source {    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // I used buffered reader because I am familiar with it :) 
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        // Create a Set to store numbers
        Set<Integer> numbers = new HashSet<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
            String line = in.readLine();
            int intValue = Integer.parseInt(line);

            // You can check you number is in the set or not
            if (numbers.contains(intValue)) {
                System.out.println("You have entered " + intValue + " before");
            } else {
                numbers.add(intValue);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow this is something advanced ... Thanks !!